# Class management to differentiate between player keys

Tags: c++, class, sdl, game-development

Making a pong clone, and having some trouble with motion and classes. So I have a class `Game` that manages two instances of a class `Paddle` and in the constructor of the `Game` class initiate the variables in the two different paddle classes and set the variable `player` to `1` or `2` based on which keys the class will respond to for motion. Then inside the `Paddle` class events function I use an `if(player == 1)` or `if(player  == 2)` to tell when keys to check for to change the y velocity of the paddle. The problem I'm having is that because the `Game` class's events function looks like this:

```
void Game::events()
{
    PlayerOne.events();
    PlayerTwo.events();
    Game_Ball.events();
}
```

And the events function and the class definition of the `Paddle` class look like this:

```
class Paddle
{
public:
    int player;
    SDL_Surface *sprite = NULL;
    float x, y, w, h;
    float yVel;
    SDL_Rect *clip;
    void events();
    void logic(Uint32 deltaTicks);
    void render();
    Paddle();
    ~Paddle();
};

void Paddle::events()
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        Uint8 *keystates = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
        if (player == 1)
        {
            if (keystates[SDLK_o] == 1)
            {
                yVel -= 100;
            }
            if (keystates[SDLK_k] == 1)
            {
                yVel += 100;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (keystates[SDLK_o] == 0)
            {
                yVel += 100;
            }
            if (keystates[SDLK_k] == 0)
            {
                yVel -= 100;
            }
        }
        if (player == 2)
        {
            if (keystates[SDLK_w] == 1)
            {
                yVel -= 100;
            }
            if (keystates[SDLK_s] == 1)
            {
                yVel += 100;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (keystates[SDLK_w] == 0)
            {
                yVel += 100;
            }
            if (keystates[SDLK_s] == 0)
            {
                yVel -= 100;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Something is happening that mixes up the keys. Usually PlayerOne uses "O/K" to move and PlayerTwo uses "W/S" to move, but sometimes I press either and the opposite class will move.  It doesn't seem to make sense. Here is the `Game` class constructor and definition

```
class Game : public GameState
{
private:
    int server;
    TTF_Font *score = NULL;
    Paddle PlayerOne;
    Paddle PlayerTwo;
    Ball Game_Ball;
public:
    SDL_Rect clip[2];
    void events();
    void logic();
    void render();
    Game();
    ~Game();
};

Game::Game()
{
    //RESOURSES
    PlayerOne.sprite = load_image("Game_sprite.png");
    PlayerTwo.sprite = load_image("Game_sprite.png");
    clip[0].x = 0;
    clip[0].y = 0;
    clip[0].w = 20;
    clip[0].h = 20;
    clip[1].x = 0;
    clip[1].y = 20;
    clip[1].w = 20;
    clip[1].h = 100;
    //PLAYER ONE
    PlayerOne.x = 420;
    PlayerOne.y = 100;
    PlayerOne.w = 60;
    PlayerOne.h = 100;
    PlayerOne.clip = &clip[1];
    PlayerOne.yVel = 0;
    PlayerOne.player = 1;
    //PLAYER TWO
    PlayerTwo.x = 60;
    PlayerTwo.y = 100;
    PlayerTwo.w = 60;
    PlayerTwo.h = 100;
    PlayerTwo.clip = &clip[1];
    PlayerTwo.yVel = 0;
    PlayerTwo.player = 2;
    //BALL
    Game_Ball.Ball_Bound.x = 190;
    Game_Ball.Ball_Bound.y = 190;
    Game_Ball.Ball_Bound.w = 60;
    Game_Ball.Ball_Bound.h = 60;
    Game_Ball.clip = &clip[0];
}
```

`player` is clearly set in both objects and the events section of the `Paddle` class clearly differentiates between them, so, why do the keys get mixed up? I could easily write another class for a second player, but that would be inefficient, I'd rather use two copies of the same class that does everything the same except the keystates. So, I'm not exactly sure what's up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On first glance it seems that you could just use:

```
    if (player == 1)
    {
        if (keystates[SDLK_o] == 1)
        {
            yVel -= 100;
        }
        if (keystates[SDLK_k] == 1)
        {
            yVel += 100;
        }
    }
    else // player == 2
    {
        if (keystates[SDLK_w] == 1)
        {
            yVel -= 100;
        }
        if (keystates[SDLK_s] == 1)
        {
            yVel += 100;
        }
    }
```

Would I be correct in guessing that when the wrong cursor moves, O would for example move the wrong cursor downwards?

Comment: You would be correct, it moves either seemingly at random, but when it moves the wrong one, it also is moved in the wrong direction. Why is that?

Comment: That'll be the `else`s you've got. i.e. when `player` is 1, you'll hit the first part in the first `if` statement, but you'll also hit the `else` part of the 2nd `if` statement i.e. if (player == 2) will lead you to the else part :-)

Comment: Oh I see. That would be the right answer. Maybe you can help on another problem with the paddles. Since the game state has three different functions to poll I think that a third of the time it doesn't register keys, requiring you to button mash if you want to move. How do I fix that?

Comment: It seems the other answer might help with that. I've only pointed out the problem obvious to me and I'm not keen to guess and give poor advice. I won't be offended if you un-accept the answer and just tag it as useful instead, since I don't appear to have fully solved your problem :-)

Comment: Oh no you totally did, the button mashing is a totally different probelm.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be the fact that you have

```
if (player == 1) {
  check keys O K pressed
}
else {
  check keys O K released
}
```

which makes no sense since this modifies values related to keys O K released on player2.

In any case you shouldn't let any game object poll for events. The main game loop should pool them once and dispatch them to the corresponding game elements, eg:

```
void gameLoop() {
    while (true) {
    draw();
    updatePositions();
    handleEvents();
  }
}

void handleEvents() {
  while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    Uint8 *keystates = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);

    if (keystates[SDLK_o]) paddle1->startMovingUp();
    else if (keystates[SDLK_k]) paddle1->startMovingDown();
    else paddle1->stopMoving();

    // same thing for player2
  }
}

Paddle::startMovingUp() {
  uvelY = -100;
}

Paddle::startMovingDown() {
  uvelY = 100;
}

Paddle::stopMoving() {
  uvelY = 0;
}

Paddle::updatePosition() {  // called on each frame
  positionY += uvelY;
}
```

You can simplify the design and just update positions in the `handleEvents()` functions but separating what is the position update from what is the management of event is a good thing to do.

Comment: Yeah I'm using a state machine so I think it's okay to let the game object to the polling. http://lazyfoo.net/articles/article06/index.php   Right? Or should the poll happen in the Game::events()` rather than the Paddle::events()`?